# Can't SSH into EC2 instance port 22: Operation timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have been accessing an EC2 instance for the last 3 months with no issues (setup by company, not myself).

Suddenly, I get the following error:

`ssh: connect to host ec2-*-***-**-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out`

When I try pinging the server I get the following:

```
wm79a-6e1:Name ***** ping ec2-*-***-**-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com
PING ec2-*-***-**-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com (*.***.**.***): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2

--- ec2-*-***-**-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com ping statistics ---
66 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

I am on a MacOS High Sierra, and can ssh into other servers just fine. Does this just mean the EC2 instance is down?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: The server could be down or the firewall rules could have changed.  Do you have access to the AWS console to check on it?

Comment: I unfortunately do not. Will check with IT for both those things, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be one of 3 reasons:

- It has a security group attached that allows inbound access to specific public IP addresses, your public IP address is not static and has changed. Check your IP address against those whitelisted.
- The instance has no elastic IP address attached, it rebooted and has a new public IP address. Check the public IP address against the IP address you're trying to connect to.
- The instance is suffering from a performance impact (such as high CPU, disk or network usage). Try rebooting the instance.